# Strange punctuation habit

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I have seen so many people on Stack Overflow (mostly those sloppy people who make a lot of grammatical/spelling mistakes) putting a space before punctuation, especially before a question mark. Is this a widely spread habit shared by programmers?

Comment: I think that's valid on some languages.

Comment: @YOU What language do you have in mind? I see it in English sentences.

Comment: And if I put 5 spaces before it, why would you care ? Some just consider it cleaner.

Comment: @Xeo I don't get what you mean.

Comment: for organizing .. maybe!

Comment: why did you call them sloppy people ?! .. i mean everybody make mistakes

Comment: @jjj Because they often coincide with not capitalizing the beginning of the sentence, writing I in lower case, omitting periods, apostrophes and commas, and making grammatica/spelling mistakes. Sorry, I don't mean to offend you.

Comment: The other things can be explained by sloppyness/laziness, but putting a space before a punctuation is different, and I couldn't understand the reason for doing it.

Comment: @Xeo: I care because it often causes the punctuation mark to break to a new line, separating it from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Related: [A space before a question or an exclamation mark. Can it be correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/a-space-before-a-question-or-an-exclamation-mark-can-it-be-correct)

Comment: See also: [Is it proper to use a colon followed immediately by a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31060/is-it-proper-to-use-a-colon-followed-immediately-by-a-hyphen)

Comment: @YOU yep, and automatic space removal [has been disabled on French SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103855/please-preserve-spaces-before-punctuation-in-title-at-least-unbreakable-ones).

Comment: Here in germany we call this "plenking" and it's annoying like hell! It ! looks ! totally ! unnatural! However, when dealing with *code* it sometimes actually makes sense for readability's sake... But in plain text it's just ugly.

Comment: @sawa It's valid (in fact, formally required AFAIK) in French. As in: "Voulez-vous un café ?" and "Je m'en fiche !"

Comment: ***Statistically***, it all comes down to this comment on EL&U: *"[@Reg, in most Indian schools, English grammar is taught from a book that was originally authored by two Englishmen: PC Wren and H Martin. The earlier editions of the book (including the one that I own) has a space before the following punctuation marks are used: question mark, exclamation mark, dash (em dash), colon and semi-colon.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645)"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the link. That is helpful information. It clears a large portion of my wonder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In some languages, like French, it is required and carried over into English by some users.

I am not aware of any research into this topic. One can speculate it comes from the use of command-line interfaces where parameters are separated by spaces. Forgetting to separate by a space leads to angry error messages and the anxiety this causes carries over into written English.

Comment: I see. That can be one factor. But I also see people who seem to be native English speakers doing it.

Comment: @sawa: low quality English is the norm in some Internet sub-cultures. Even my Polish colleague, who has a Ph.D. in biochemistry (and know how to write proper English), use this hard-to-read English in email. But it is a lost cause to try to change such habits.

Comment: I understand that, but I can usually distinguish a sloppy English native writing from low quality English written by non-natives. They both make mistakes, but the quality is different. In majority of the cases, it does not seem that putting a space before question mark is due to being a non-native speaker. Some cases may be, though.

Comment: I disagree with your speculation. A punctuation mark at the end of a sentence would no more be a "new parameter" than would a trailing slash at the end of a directory path. If anything, using a CLI would train users *not* to insert superfluous spaces!

Comment: Edits appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Quoted from [about.com](http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-punctuation.htm)

> **Two-part punctuation marks In French**
>   a space is required both before and
>   after all two- (or more) part
>   punctuation marks and symbols,
>   including : ; « » ! ? % $ #

Comment: I see. Maybe that can affect their English. But, I still don't think that the majority of people doing it are native French speakers. By the way, thanks for the quote. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally add a space before punctuation to avoid confusion. For example, "I dislike String#upcase!, but I really like String#upcase !".

I'd say it's not so much common with programmers, but any [user generated content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-generated_content) on the Internet, especially that written by idiots. You'd probably see it with [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube) comments as well. I asked a similar question on Japanese Language and Usage: *[Is Japanese that lacks proofreading likely to contain bad spelling or grammar?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/is-japanese-that-lacks-proofreading-likely-to-contain-bad-spelling-or-grammar)*.

Bad English must be *[chotto muzukashii](http://www.japanese123.com/chottoippai.htm)* when you yourself have put a fair amount of effort into learning the language, *ne*?

Comment: *You* might think that avoids confusion, but I have *no idea* what that sentence says.

Comment: @TheEstablishment edited accordingly.

Comment: So, what you actually mean is: "I dislike `String#upcase!`, but I really like `String#upcase`!" :-)

Comment: Yes. That's the feeling I have.