# Please don't escape & in a comment if it's part of an &nbsp;

Tags: feature-request, comments

*(Related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103855/please-preserve-spaces-before-punctuation-in-title-at-least-unbreakable-ones) request, and [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/is-there-an-explanation-for-why-there-is-a-space-before-certain-punctuation-marks) question)*

For better or for worse, in French, one is *supposed* to insert a non-breakable space before various punctuation (`? : ! ;`).

I can hand-code `&nbsp;`s into questions, but they get escaped in comments.

Is there any chance you could 'escape' the escaping for us? :)

**UPDATE** I've rolled a [user-script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2569/convert-ctrl-space-to-non-break-space-for-flu) to convert Ctrl-spaces to non-break-spaces (inspired by Frédéric's answer below).

Comment: `For better or for worse, in French, one is supposed to insert a non-breakable space before various punctuation.` This is an english website...or did I miss something here?

Comment: @Strait, yes, you [missed](http://french.stackexchange.com) something :)

Answer (score 15):

That would indeed be useful, even though special-casing a single HTML entity like that might not be the right thing to do (there probably are other entities that would benefit from the same treatment).

However, maybe we don't need special support to achieve this. There are ways to input actual [no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) characters, depending on your operating system and graphical environment. Wikipedia has a nice list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods).

I was able to test the following key sequences:

- Everything on Windows: hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, (on the numeric keypad) <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- GTK-based Firefox on Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>.
- On Mac, <kbd>Alt</kbd> +        <kbd>Space</kbd>        .

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31H-CGFkkLL._SL500_AA300_.jpg :(

Comment: Whoa! You just taught  me how to type unicode characters on my linux machine! +1

Comment: @Benjol, no keypad? Not even through an `Fn` modifier like on laptops? That's indeed unfortunate :)

Comment: Fréd, woops! Well spotted, I just have to hit Num Lock, silly me ! (Not very convenient though, I think I'm going to try and hack together a gm script for alt+space!)

Comment: This is the first occasion on which I've *wanted* a Mac for reasons of simplicity...

Comment: .    testing    some    spaces.