# Automatic capitalization of "i"

Tags: feature-request, editor, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can 'u' and 'i' part ways?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105180/can-u-and-i-part-ways)

I've observed that a significant number of people use "i" instead of "I"

Sample:

> i create a iframe to get acess token in facebook but it require redirections to another page. and i dont get answer in the same iframe instead page entirely redirect.

In English this is incorrect, but it can be corrected automatically without much effort in submission time. It will keep the Stack Overflow "nice". Just thought to add this as a feature request.

**UPDATE**: We ignore "i"s if they are in code sample tags.

Comment: I have an existing feature request for this, check out the link.

Comment: does that mean we'll change "u" to "you" and "tks" to "thanks" and so on and so forth? Not capatilising I's and using text speak is just plain lazyness and SE should not make it easier to ignore or tolerate it. Granted, it's probably a bit of regex name matching, but there's probably better things for the SE team to be working on.

Comment: @tombull89 I'm sure there are many other things that they are working on.  I think this *is* important for people landing on the site via search engines.  It makes everything just a bit more presentable.  I know it doesn't correct the behavior, but I think its function as prevention could outweigh that of training (as is the case with other filters and corrections like removing the greeting from posts).

Comment: `for (I = 0; I < 10; I++) printf("My C code doesn't agree\n");`

Comment: @Klas: The question already indicated that this wouldn't happen inside code blocks. Moreover, changing the case of a variable wouldn't affect the execution of the program.

Comment: @ἸησοῦςCaswell: In some programming languages, variables may not begin with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0):

So the next time someone writes `for i = 0`... I won't even continue :-)

Comment: For i = 0 should be written in code tags. We omit the tags without processing. I am talking about the text that are NOT in tags

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara The ones that write `i create` forget even to format code :-)

Comment: hmm... Good point xanatos. But they will see the output and they will learn to format the code. Isn't it?

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara And the ones that receives -infinite to their questions and have their question closed learn to write better questions, right? :-)

Comment: Yes, If a user really wants to get use of SO he should learn. If he/she face with that situation once, he/she have to (will) learn to how to write a question properly. I've never seen a user that writes questions of that type again and again. What do you think?

Comment: If the quality filter is trained to pick up unformatted code, processing it as such would allow an "i", "u", etc. filter on a second pass which ignored code blocks.

Comment: @Chathuranga: Code variables are not the only reason to use lowercase i. For example, with such feature you wouldn't be able to post your question as intended: *I've observed that a significant number of people use i instead of "I"*

Comment: @GoranJovic I was trying to find a good composable dot in Unicode to merge with the Turkish dotless i but I wasn't able to find one similar enough :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such feature would help, at least not if it comes to SO.

An `i` often is used as counting variable in programming languages and automatically uppercasing it to `I` would yield strange results.

Comment: Any such filter would probably have to ignore code blocks (and backtick'ed code) anyway.