# Is using lower case for the first person singular pronoun (I) acceptable?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can 'u' and 'i' part ways with Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105180/can-u-and-i-part-ways-with-stack-exchange)

A lot of posts on SO seem to use lower case i.  For example:

> i can't figure this out. ive tried this and ive tried that.

For a pedant like me, this is sloppiness worth correcting.

But, is there a shift in English-language usage that I've missed?

Is this worth editing?

Comment: i usually capitalize the letter i, but sometimes i dont.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is there a shift in English-language usage that I've missed?

No. But there are *many* Stack Overflow users that are not from England or the US and don't see the issue at all (not to say that all people in England or the US do care).

Personally, when editing a post I will correct these as well (but not if there isn't anything else to fix).

Comment: Thanks for that. Very picky editing bothers me :)

Comment: +1. I usually combine it with correcting MSSQL -> SQL Server (that one annoys the crap out of me for some reason), removing the sql-server tag from a MySQL question, or fixing horribly formatted code samples / sample data.

Comment: What about Australia and Canada?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Didn't think they were significant for the discussion, backwaters that they are.

Comment: @Remou Sorry for any of my edits that have passed your way, then. ;-)

Comment: `but not if there isn't anything else to fix` +1+1+1+1+1