# Why was the *pronoun* tag removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, meta-tags

I recently asked a couple questions with the [pronouns](/questions/tagged/pronouns) tag.  A mega-high-rep user removed that tag.  Now, the tag doesn't exist.

[image: screenshot showing defunct tag]

What gives?  Why was the [pronouns](/questions/tagged/pronouns) tag deleted?

---

Update: I don't know if it was the same person who removed the tag from my questions, and then later removed the tag from the site.  Maybe a tag disappears once it is no longer associated with any questions.

To respond to some comments I decided to link to my comment where I [asked him why he did it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334203/are-there-any-objections-to-using-singular-they-for-everyone/334205#comment1094713_334205).  When I found that page again, I discovered that he actually had already responded to my question (but I hadn't read his response because he forgot to ping me).

Anyway, his response was

> IMO it's already covered by code-of-conduct.

Personally, I disagree; a code of conduct hopefully covers a whole lot more than just pronouns.

Comment: It's simply not possible for somebody of high reputation to remove a tag *from the system itself* single-handed.

Comment: @JasonBassford If a tag is removed from all questions it's deleted by a scheduled task that runs once a day. I have deleted a lot of tags that way

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Yes, of course. The question didn't seem to describe the situation in that way. At least to me, it read as if somebody deliberately (as we informally call it) *burninated* a tag, something that can't be done by a single high-reputation user.

Comment: There is no contradiction between *it's already covered by code-of-conduct* and *a code of conduct hopefully covers a whole lot more than just pronouns*.

Comment: Great question. If we're going to make pronouns a big issue, it goes to follow that questions should be tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 22):

Rhetorical question: Why does this site need a tag named **pronouns**?

It looks to be a meta-tag. What about **code-of-conduct-pronouns**? But before creating such tag...

(more rhetorical questions)

- How many questions already exist that could use that tag?
- Are there already experts in the subject of that tag who could be interested in following it?

---

The following was added to the question after I posted the first revision of this answer:

> Anyway, his response was
>
> > IMO it's already covered by code-of-conduct.
>
> Personally, I disagree; a code of conduct hopefully covers a whole lot more than just pronouns.

As I understand it, the comment author meant that a new tag is not required because we already have [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct). Again, rhetorical questions:

- Why do we need something like **code-of-conduct-pronouns**?

  - Are already other concepts on the CoC that are being discussed separately?
  - Are there people that is interested on **pronouns** but no not on other concepts like **being constructive**?
  - Is the CoC so complex / controversial that each concept should be discussed separately?

Answer (score 21):

> Why was the *pronoun* tag removed?

Let me quote the [Help Center](/help/privileges/create-tags):

> #### When should I create new tags?
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question *does* cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

The existing tag that covers the topic of these questions is [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct). This isn't the first time that pronouns are the subject of discussion on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [Any thoughts on how to react to gender-specific language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176181/295232)
- [Does Stack Overflow aspire to a standard of gender-neutral language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223412/295232)
- [How should I refer to the OP?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318392/295232)

(from [searching for 'pronouns'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=Newest&q=pronouns))

Lastly, while if you're even a little bit aware of the current events, it's crystal clear what we're talking about when we use the word 'pronouns'. But in a few years, it may be less so, especially for new users. They could equally well think 'hey, pronouns are on-topic here, let me ask an English grammar question about them'. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138049/295232) is also about pronouns, but not in the way we're currently talking about them. A more specific tag (maybe [code-of-conduct-pronouns] as [suggested by Ruben](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334677/295232)) *might* have more merit, but I think the volume is simply too low right now and hopefully it won't grow too much in the future.

---

> Maybe a tag disappears once it is no longer associated with any questions.

You're right: tags are [automatically deleted (after ~24 hours) if they have no questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40725/295232), or [(after six months) if they have only one question and no tag wiki or tag excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/295232).

---

> (but I hadn't read his response because he forgot to ping me).

I'm sorry about that, I assumed that since you posted the last comment it would *automatically* ping you. It turns out it doesn't, so I've added this exception to the [proposed FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/295232).

Comment: Thanks for following up, and sorry I missed your comment initially. // There is no tag for `gender` either.  There are lots of possibilities, e.g. `pronouns-and-gender`, `pronoun-use`, `CoC-pronoun-use`, etc.  I don't think I have enough rep here to create a tag so I hope you or someone else will give it some thought and create something.

Comment: @aparente001 It seems to me we could use an inclusion tag for discussions about being inclusive that are not necessarily CoC issues.

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways - I hope you will create such a tag.  It would be best if you did it, rather than me, because I might not have understood exactly your idea.

Answer (score 14):

Ping that user to ask them -- you can always directly ping anyone who edits your post. And if you disagree for a substantive reason, roll back their edit.

I suspect the reason may be that they don't believe such a tag is worthwhile / should not exist at all, and don't want it to exist to potentially mislead other people. But no one can speak for them.

Comment: I pinged the person and asked him why he removed the tag. // I can't restore the tag to my questions because it doesn't exist any more.  I don't have enough rep to recreate it, and I wouldn't do that anyway because edit wars are no fun.  But thanks for trying to help. // Can you explain the *potentially mislead* idea you mentioned at the end of your post?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. What I mean is, if someone doesn't think the tag should exist, then its existence would wrongly imply people should use it. Taghounds are (_in general_ rightfully) worried that leaving a tag around is like a broken window. It might become popular, and then it becomes a _lot_ harder to clean up if it needs to go away later.

Answer (score -1):

Let’s talk about the *ethos* of a good tag.

Now, I hate tags (oddly enough. I hate many things!).

On the other hand, folks have pretty good ideas about tags I hate less. While this is meta, meta tags are pretty disliked.

As per the *[meta tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-tags/info)* tag wiki,

> Meta tags are tags which describe something other than the question's content--such as the author's skill level, motivation, or current take on it. Alternatively, they may be ill-defined concepts which make consistent application of the tag difficult or impossible.

Arguably a pronoun tag kind of falls under the last.

Now if you wanted to do this properly - let’s consider a few things that would ease the way

- Is there a reasonable amount of support from the community?

On a regular site, this would be on meta. On meta, well you can ask on meta. Conventionally you'd talk about consensus, but let’s be realistic here.

- Can you define the topic as a tag wiki and a tag wiki excerpt?

I've not seen an effort to, and a meta post should hash this out

- does it help searchability for a stand-alone topic of general interest?

At least the last time I removed it, the tag didn't meet any of this criteria. *Maybe* the last, but there's a reason it's the last.

Comment: Would you kindly point me to a post that has instructions for how one is supposed to go about creating a new tag?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions) . [This](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) seems appropriate too. Via [The Faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Thanks, but that's a lot of thises.  Care to narrow it down to one or two?  I'm working on deadline.

Comment: You asked. I don't see any deadline. You want to get it done right, with tags that seem controversial - they've been rolled back, you either get some community support you can point to me, or read and cross all the ts and dot all the is. My post seems a reasonable level of specific suggestions that would work

Comment: Sorry.  The deadlines I'm dealing with are my own.  They have nothing to do with you or SE.  I'm asking, as a favor, for you to simplify and streamline, if you can.  I appreciate that you want to be *complete* in your guidance -- but I've got several very tight deadlines so I'm asking for your assistance, in narrowing down the amount of reading I'll need to do, to follow the recommended procedure.

Comment: But... I don't think the tag is valid. I rolled back the edit. The *best* I can do is improve your chances of the tag being created and sticking. I gave a short bit of advice, when you asked for pointing you at the post, I found and pointed you at the appropriate faqs. My answer *is* the simple version. My comment is the fuller version.

Comment: It wasn't your text that was too involved.  That was fine.  I understood what you wrote in your comment.  The problem is that you have pointed me to four different links.  Normally I'd be okay reading four different links -- but right now I have to limit the work I do on things other than the crunch stuff I have to do by some very tight deadlines.  I hope you understand.

Comment: Okay, I've had a look at your links.  The first two are identical -- perhaps you accidentally pasted in a wrong link.  None of them tell me best practice for creating a new tag.  However, your helpful link the the FAQ led me to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146950/287826.  I will attempt to follow the instructions posted there.