# Texting abbreviations in answers and questions

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I am relatively new to Stack Exchange. I have started to frequent the Math and Programming (stackoverflow.com) forums. I have been active in other similar forums in the past. Those forums strongly encouraged against using texting-style abbreviations such as single letters for words. What is the general policy in that regards here?

p.s. My apologies if this has been discussed before. The list of "Similar Questions" to the right does not appear to have a thread that looks like this question. If there is one somewhere, please post a link.

Comment: <John Lydon>Thiiis is not a forum!</John Lydon>

Comment: @DanielFischer There is no other word in my vocabulary to describe what *this* is. =p

Comment: A question and answer site?

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess that would work...seems a bit verbose, though.

Comment: Well, Q&A is an abbreviation that's accepted hereabouts too.

Comment: @DanielFischer That works...and is a little ironic (or maybe just amusing) given the topic of my question.

Comment: I am aware of the irony. By the way, welcome to Stack Exchange, I think you'll be a valuable contributor, judging by this question.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I hope to be able to contribute with both questions and answers.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105180/can-u-and-i-part-ways-with-stack-exchange

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's discouraged. If you use them, though, chances are somebody will just edit your post to remove them right away, so you're not going to see many examples anyway.

Answer (score 7):

The policy here is "Don't use txtspk". You should use complete words and sentences, but normal and common abbreviations, e.g. i.e., are acceptable.