# Bug with question mark in a title - (space goes here)?

Tags: bug

I was entering [this question on Russian.SE](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) and attempted to put two question marks in the title after the hyphen (I first tried to use title *Смеяться - рассмешить, улыбаться - ??*)

When I submitted the question, the title was changed to *Смеяться - рассмешить, улыбаться -?*

I can understand (although not necessarily agree with) replacing two consecutive question marks in the title with one, but I believe removing the space before the question mark is a bug.  While in most cases it would be a valid scenario (i.e. question at the end of the sentence), if the question mark follows a space after another punctuation sign, then the space should not be removed.

Comment: Should that hyphen be there in the first place? Does it make sense in Russian?

Comment: @Yannis, no, not really.

Comment: @YannisRizos in this case, yes.  The question is about word relations.  The meaning of the question is "word1 - word2, word3 - ?", asking to come up with a word that has similar relation to word3 as word2 to word1.  An (oversimplified) example English question could be "heavy - light, long - ?"

Comment: @AleksG, in that case you have a bad title. I understood it as "Does Смеяться mean рассмешить or улыбаться?".

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall hm... I haven't thought about that interpretation...  I can definitely change the question title, however my question remains: should the space be automatically removed in all cases?

Comment: btw you should have posted this on [Meta 
Russian Language and Usage](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AleksG Spaces before question marks don't make sense in all languages I know (all three of them ;).

Comment: @AleksG, it probably gets removed because most of the languages do not have any spaces in front of punctuation marks. At least I don't know about a language that does. Not to mention that "-?" is not something you would usually see as the end of a sentence.

Comment: @YannisRizos agree - in normal speach, however they may make sense when trying to present structured relations (with an unknown, represented by that question mark).

Comment: @AleksG Not in any of the three languages I know. But, I don't know Russian.

Comment: @YannisRizos (Structurally, Russian isn't very different from English)

Comment: @YannisRizos: [French uses a space before question marks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103855/please-preserve-spaces-before-punctuation-in-title-at-least-unbreakable-ones) (and possibly other punctuations as well).

Comment: related: [Any authoritative source on British rules on space before question mark?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14003/any-authoritative-source-on-british-rules-on-space-before-question-mark)

Comment: The answer would be "вызвать улыбку", which means "to evoke a smile", by the way, as in "Его замечание вызвало у меня улыбку" which roughly translates to "His remark made me smile".

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want to be able to enter your title in this particular format?

The Google translation of the Russian comes out as:

> Laugh - laugh, smile -?

Ignoring the fact that the translation is incorrect, this isn't a very good question title. I would suggest that you need to rework your title so it makes more sense.

As you can see on [this wikipedia page about the *space*](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BC_.D1.81.D0.BE_.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BF.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F), no spaces are put before punctuation marks in Russian.

Comment: That translation is definitely incorrect; and I now rewrote the question title, however my initial question remains: do we need to always remove that space?  And the fact that Google does it is irrelevant here.

Comment: @AleksG - yes you're right, what Google does is irrelevant. But to answer your question about the space. Yes we do need to remove it.

Comment: That's roughly "laugh - set laughing, smile -?"

Answer (score -3):

If I understand you correctly, it is another of those situations where you need to cheat the system to ask a question on [pr0blems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles):

> Bug with question mark in a title - (space goes here)?

or maybe this works better

> Bug with question mark in a title - __?

Comment: "Why are spaces in front of question marks removed from the title?"

Comment: @Bart another one of those who don't get it

Comment: Then you might want to express yourself more clearly. Judging from the downvote there's at least one other user who doesn't get it.