# Why can't I end a question with "..."?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

Recently, I've posted [a question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104023/we-are-number-one-but) with `...` (three dots in a row) at the end of the question title. To my surprise, it was removed. I tried re-editing it into it, but it just got removed again.

[image: Editing screen]

Trying to edit in `...`

[image: it doesn't show up in the title]

Result: No `...` in question title

What and why exactly is preventing me from typing `...` at the end of a question title?

### Update

<s>Apparently, using `<space>...` works.</s> The ellipsis character works fine.

[image: ellipsis char]

For reference, the site I was trying to post this on was [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), where my question/challenge was perfectly clear and valid, and the faux-ellipsis was used for decorative effect.

Comment: Why would you want to? How would it help your question be clearer or easier to find?

Comment: There's a system in place to automatically 'correct' low quality titles. The details should be somewhere here on Meta.

Comment: @Glorfindel I'd gladly mark this as duplicate if I could get the post you mean?

Comment: I couldn't find it, but I'm on mobile so it was hard to search. May give it a try later today.

Comment: Looks like you can end a question title with an ellipsis character `…` at least on MSE. See edit history of this question.

Comment: I think a question title should always end in a question mark.

Comment: @PolyGeo The site he/she is trying to post to is code golf. The "questions" there are more challenges than actual questions AFAIK.

Comment: @MartinSmith there was no mention of Code Golf in the question body so the involvement of that atypical site was only discernible by following a link which I didn't.

Comment: Regarding your edit it is nothing to do with the space, the ellipsis character is a single character. This is different from typing three dots.

Comment: @MartinSmith Aplologies, I thought it was three dots.

Comment: @PolyGeo, a question can be a "bug".

Comment: @alldani I'm yet to see a "bug" that cannot be titled in the form of a question.

Comment: It probably always can, I'm saying at times it works without too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In 2011, somebody brought this up on this site for the first time that I can find.

[This answer says:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115352/311528)

> The logic for trailing punctuation re-writing becomes.
>
> - Multiple ? collapsed into one
> - Multiple . collapsed into one
> - ?! and similar collapsed into ?
> - Spaces before trailing punctuation removed (with one exception)
> - Everywhere but the trilogy, multiple ! collapsed in one

Your question title seems to fall under rule #2: "multiple '.' collapsed into one". If you want to disable this for the whole site of Code Golf SE, you should probably make a feature request for that.

Note the exception referenced in "trailing punctuation removed" is [French Stack Exchange](https://french.stackexchange.com/), for which [that rule was disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103855/please-preserve-spaces-before-punctuation-in-title-at-least-unbreakable-ones). That was because French grammar required/preferred the extra space before the punctuation.

Comment: Most likely a combination of the 2nd and 4th rule. I'm honestly not sure about that, it's probably an undocumented removal of `<space>.` or something.

Comment: There is at least one missing rule. If the title ends in "[`etc.`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/etc.#Phrase)" it will incorrectly be replaced by "`etc`"

Comment: @PeterMortensen yeah, OP had a now deleted comment about that. My best guess is that it's a combination of the 2nd and 4th rules.